# The name 'Helper' does not exist in the current context, Plotly library for Blazor

Tags: c#, plotly, blazor

I'm following this documentation for Plotly, a Blazor library for creating graphs:

https://github.com/LayTec-AG/Plotly.Blazor

In the tutorial, this line of code is provided:

```
private async Task AddData(int count = 100)
{
    if (!(chart.Data.FirstOrDefault() is Scatter scatter)) return;
    var (x, y) = Helper.GenerateData(scatter.X.Count + 1, scatter.X.Count + 1 + count);

    await chart.ExtendTrace(x, y, data.IndexOf(scatter));
}
```

I copied this snippet into my Blazor project, but I get the error message shown in the title. Helper does not seem to be a class defined anywhere in the example source code so I'm a bit confused as to what 'Helper' is referring to.

Comment: It's in `Plotly.Blazor.Examples/Helper.cs`. In a 'normal' project you would load some real data at that point.

Comment: To add to @HenkHolterman comment - you'll find it here -https://github.com/LayTec-AG/Plotly.Blazor/blob/master/Plotly.Blazor.Examples/Helper.cs